# Javascript function and Array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to cut some values from an array, for example i want to cut 1 from it's position and return array as (3,5,4,6,2,7), but there is an error saying splice is not a function.

```
function findMin() {
   var arr = arguments;
   arr.splice(1,1);
   return arr[0];
 }
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = findMin(1,3,5,4,6,2,7);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is [`arguments` isn't an array, but an array-like object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

The usual solution is to use `slice` to get an array from an array-like object. And as the normal purpose of `slice` is to get a slice from an array, here's a solution giving you a copy of `arguments` without the first element:

```
function findMin() {
   return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
}
```

**Notes**

1. Manipulating `arguments`, even using `slice` has a performance impact on the whole function in which you do it. Avoid it when you can.
2. Thanks to ES6 (the next iteration of the standard behind JavaScript), [we'll be able to use `Array.from` instead of slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)  in the near future.

Answer (score 4):

`arguments` isn't an array, it's *array-like*. You can get a copy of its contents as an array like this:

```
var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
```

...and then you can use array operations on it.

Two other issues with the code:

- Indexes you use with `splice` start at `0`, not `1`
- You're returning the (new) first entry, not the array

But note that for your *specific* task, you don't need to go through all those operations, you can just use `slice` directly; [Denys Séguret shows you that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30543295/157247).

Here's an example just using `slice` to copy `arguments`, without combining it with the other code, with the other issues above fixed as well:

```js
function findMin() {
  var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
  arr.splice(0, 1);
  return arr;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = findMin(1, 3, 5, 4, 6, 2, 7);
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: There's a simpler solution ;)

Comment: @DenysSéguret: For this *specific* problem, yes, quite true. :-) I was sort of just addressing the `arguments` aspect.